# Finding the Intersection of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the problem below.

> $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> $$U = \text{Span}(t^3 + 4t^2 - t + 3, t^3 + 5t^2 + 5, 3t^3 + 10t^2 -5t + 5)$$
>   $$W = \text{Span}(t^3 + 4t^2 + 6, t^3 + 2t^2 - t + 5, 2t^3 + 2t^2 -3t + 9)$$
>
> What is $U \cap W$?

To work out $U \cap W$, I try to solve:

$$\alpha_1(t^3 + 4t^2 - t + 3) +\alpha_2(t^3 + 5t^2 + 5) +\alpha_3(3t^3 + 10t^2 -5t + 5) = \beta_1(t^3 + 4t^2 + 6) + \beta_2(t^3 + 2t^2 - t + 5) + \beta_3(2t^3 + 2t^2 -3t + 9).$$

After reducing a linear system, this gives:

\begin{array}{}
\alpha_1  + 5\alpha_3 - \beta_2 - 3\beta_3 & = 0 \\
\alpha_2 - 2 \alpha_3 + 2\beta_2 + 6\beta_3 & = 0 \\
\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 + 5\beta_3 & = 0\end{array}

I have two questions.

1) I was under the impression that when, solving a linear system via parametrisation, it doesn't matter which of the variables you parametrise, but in this case I believe you have to parametrise $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1$. Is this true?

2) When I solve the linear system, I can work out $\alpha_3$ in terms of the parametrised $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. I.e., $\alpha_3 = \frac{-2\alpha_1 - \alpha_2}{8}$. Does this mean that
$$U \cap W = \Big\{\alpha_1(t^3 + 4t^2 - t + 3) +\alpha_2(t^3 + 5t^2 + 5) +\alpha_3(3t^3 + 10t^2 -5t + 5)\ |\ \alpha_3 = \frac{-2\alpha_1 - \alpha_2}{8}\Big\}\ ?$$